# amCharts 4 - How to Access Currently-Hovered Series Data/Color in XYChart in JavaScript

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I'm trying to access the currently-hovered series data and color via JavaScript.  The data is available to the legend and tooltip, but I'm not sure how to directly access it.

It's possible to place the legend in an external container, but their code creates a lot of additional containers/wrappers which makes formatting difficult.  [This Github question](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/1202) addresses it, but no answer was provided.

Perhaps events could be used to detect changes in the legend text or tspan elements and then grab the new text, but I'm not sure how to do this (using amCharts events) and how efficient it would be (especially with multiple series and/or charts with synced cursors).

[Another idea](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/976) was to get the data based on cursor position, but this seems inefficient (`cursorpositionchanged` fires too often - on mouse/cursor movement even when the series data hasn't changed).  Maybe it could be done more efficiently based on change in dateAxis value?  For example, using the `positionchanged` event listener:

```
chart.cursor.lineX.events.on('positionchanged', function() {
    // get series data and do something with it
});
```

At least when using `chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis`, the `positionchanged` event only seems to fire when the cursor jumps to a new value.  So it would be more efficient than an event that fired on mouse/cursor movement.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

By currently-hovered, I am referring to the series data and color accessible via the tooltip (for example) with the mouse over the chart.

Examples: [CandlestickSeries](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oOVLOd) and [LineSeries](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/line-chart-with-scroll-and-zoom/)

Comment: Can you please provide an example? Series is vague, there are many different kinds of series. Also, what do you mean by currently-hovered, e.g. via chart cursor or the mouse is directly over the series? If the former, then you would probably have to translate the cursor's position to something plotted on the chart, I don't see how that's inefficient.

Comment: @notacouch I updated the question to (hopefully) answer your questions

Answer (score 1):

One method you can try is to set an [adapter](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/adapters/) for `tooltipText` on the object of concern. Since this may run multiple times especially via a chart cursor, perhaps keep track of changes to the tooltip via monitoring the unique value, e.g. in the samples provided that would be the `date` field. The data you're looking for can be found in the adapter's `target.tooltipDataItem`. The color, if on the series, will be `target.tooltipDataItem.component.fill` (in the case of the line series example, the `target` *is* the line series and has no change of color, so you can just use `target.fill`), otherwise e.g. in the case of CandleStick series the color would be on the candle stick, or `column`, i.e. via `target.tooltipDataItem.column.fill`.

Sample adapter for LineSeries:

```js
var tooltipDate;
series.adapter.add("tooltipText", function(text, target) {
  // data via target.tooltipDataItem.dataContext
  console.log('text adapter; color: ', target.tooltipDataItem.component.fill.hex);
  if (tooltipDate !== target.tooltipDataItem.dataContext.date) {
    console.log('new tooltip date, do something');
    tooltipDate = target.tooltipDataItem.dataContext.date;
  }
  // note: in this case: component === target 
  return text;
});
```

Demo:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/9f621f6a0e5d0441fe55b99a25094e2b

Sample Candlestick series adapter:

```js
var tooltipDate;
series.adapter.add("tooltipText", function(text, target) {
  // data via target.tooltipDataItem.dataContext
  console.log('text adapter; color: ', target.tooltipDataItem.column.fill.hex);
  if (tooltipDate !== target.tooltipDataItem.dataContext.date) {
    console.log('new tooltip date, do something');
    tooltipDate = target.tooltipDataItem.dataContext.date;
  }
  return text;
});
```

Demo:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/80343b59241b72cf8246c266d70281a7

Let us know if this is making sense, and if the adapter route is a good point in time to capture changes, data, color, as well as if it's efficient enough a manner to go about this.

Comment: how can I get the color of a LineSeries where the line color is set using `lineSeries.propertyFields.stroke` and `lineSeries.propertyFields.fill`?

Comment: Can you give an example of why you wouldn't be able to use `target.tooltipDataItem.dataContext[target.component.propertyFields.stroke]` and `target.tooltipDataItem.dataContext[target.component.propertyFields.fill]`